# How to send data from JSP to Action with <s:a> in Struts2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I want to achieve that clicking the title, the matching id is sent to the Action, but id in the Action is always zero.

The Action uses the id to search the matching record in database and show in another jsp.

```xml
<s:iterator id="n" value="news">
<tr>
    <td>
    <s:url action="GETNEWS" var="getNews">
        <s:a href="%{getNews}">
            <s:property value="#n.title" />
            <s:hidden name="id" value="#n.id" />
        </s:a>
    </s:url>
    </td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Post your action class code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` in `<s:iterator>` is deprecated (unless you are using an aeon-old version). Use `var` instead.

Use `<s:param>` inside `<s:url>` (and, for a better coding, remember to specify the namespace). 
Then reference the `<s:url>` from `<s:a>`.

Finally, ensure you have the right Setter in your action.

```xml
<s:iterator var="n" value="news">
<tr>
    <td>

        <s:url action="GETNEWS" namespace="/" var="getNews">
            <s:param name="id">
                <s:property value="#n.id" />
            </s:param>
        </s:url>

        <s:a href="%{getNews}">
            <s:property value="#n.title" />
        </s:a>

    </td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to up-vote this question if you liked it, thank you @倪裕镇

Answer (score 0):

Use `<s:param>` tag to send value to server.So your code would look like

```
<s:iterator id="n" value="news">
<tr>
    <td>
    <s:url action="GETNEWS" var="getNews">
        <s:param name="id"><s:property value="#n.id"/></s:param>
        <s:a href="%{getNews}">
            <s:property value="#n.title"/>
        </s:a>
    </s:url>
    </td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
```